# Will I be charged for data Transfer between Snowflake and On Premise?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please can somebody explain the followings:

1. If Snowflake Virtual warehouse is Resumed and running but there is no query running on this Warehouse? Still we will be charged?
2. I have a report or Excel on premise which is pointed to Snowflake and reading data from snowflake. Will be changed for data transfer (https://www.snowflake.com/pricing/pricing-guide/) or It is just going to be computation charge?
3. If I have a SSAS Cube on premise and Snowflake is source for this cube. Processing cube will be treated as Data Transfer between cloud and On Premise?

We are looking for Hybrid solution:
Keep SSAS cubes on premise and source of cube is going to be snowflake.

Answer (score 6):

When you start a virtual warehouse, the server(s) it is running on is reserved for you. 
 You rent it for the time it is running, regardless of what you use it for, running queries or running idle.

If you do not run queries 24/7, the best is to configure `AUTO SUSPEND` and `AUTO RESUME` so that the virtual warehouse is shut down when you do not need it and restarted again when needed, everything automatic.  See the documentation for the [`CREATE WAREHOUSE`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-warehouse.html) command for details on `AUTO SUSPEND` and `AUTO RESUME`.

Please have a look at [Understanding Snowflake Virtual Warehouse, Storage, and Cloud Services Usage](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/credits.html) for details.

Snowflake doesn't charge for data transfer related to queries including SSAS cube processing, only for bulk replication between cloud storage sites (which is not in your current scenario, I believe).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. If Snowflake Virtual warehouse is Resumed and running but there is no query running on this Warehouse? Still we will be charged?

Yes, it will be charged even if there's no query running. However, you can specify a warehouse to shift into suspend mode if no queries are actively running. Once suspended, charges are also suspended for idle compute time.

https://www.snowflake.com/blog/how-usage-based-pricing-delivers-a-budget-friendly-cloud-data-warehouse/

> 2. I have a report or Excel on premise which is pointed to Snowflake and reading data from snowflake. Will be changed for data transfer
>    (https://www.snowflake.com/pricing/pricing-guide/) or It is just going
>    to be computation charge?
> 3. If I have a SSAS Cube on premise and Snowflake is source for this cube. Processing cube will be treated as Data Transfer between cloud
>    and On Premise?

No, and no. Snowflake doesn't charge egress data transfer unless it falls into one of the following use cases:

1. Unloading Data from Snowflake
2. Database Replication
3. External Functions

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/billing-data-transfer.html#data-transfer-billing-use-cases